# prompt choice: last choice is not in the same style in Skype for business channel

Tags: botframework, prompt

prompt choice with liststyle as list. The choice options are not in the same style: all choice options are in bold except last one, in Skype for Business channel.
ex:
**1.** track order
**2.** availability
3. status

Answer (score 0):

The styles of the different channels are controlled by the channels themselves, Skype, Facebook, etc. With the exception of webchat channel, you can't actually change the styling, and even then, it's limited.

That being said, you can put an issue in on the [BotBuilder repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) or the [Skype Dev repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/skype-dev-bots) to have it looked into.